# Changing label positions in Flot, using the Spider plug-in (or using a background image?)

Tags: jquery, background, cross-browser, diagram, flot

I'm currently making a web app that relies upon Flot, and specifically the "Spider" plugin - available at jumware[1]. However I have 10 different types of data for each series, so there's 10 different datapoints each with a label. Unfortunately the plugin doesn't handle labelling so well - and I either have to set the labels so small you can't read them, or their large enough to read but clutter the diagram up.

I've tried setting a background image on the div, however that worked in all other browsers but is a known problem when using IE and Excanvas.[2] Naturally I need this app to be working with all browsers, and as it's not on behalf of my personal website - I can't really afford to block IE users.

**So my question is basically** -
 - Is there a way of moving the labels in a flot diagram, or removing them all and drawing them manually?
 - Or, perhaps more easily - does anyone have a hack around the div/excanvas bug in IE? This would be the perfect solution!

Thanks in advance guys!

[1] http://www.jumware.com/Includes/jquery/Flot/Examples/spider.html
[2] http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=125